# How to assert state in unit test (React JS) while state is updating in axios call?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, enzyme

hi i am having problem in asserting state in unit test case while it is updating in axios call.
This is my axios call

```
import axios from 'axios'
getData = () => {
    axios.get('/events/sept/week2/1097338')
        .then(res =>{
            if(res.status == 200){
                let resposne = res.data.resposne
                this.setState({weekData:response})
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {console.log(error)})
}
```

this is my test case

```
test("test axios for week data",() => {
    const mock = new MockAdapter (axios)
    mock.onGet('/events/sept/week2/1097338').reply(200,{response:['raspberry']})
    const wrapper = shallow(<Component/>)
    wrapper.instance().getData()
    expect(wrapper.state('weekData')).toBe(['raspberry'])
})
```

the state weekData is updating in Component when i call
wrapper.instance().getData(), i have checked this. Its not updating in wrapper and my assertion is failing like : expected : ['raspberry'] ,  received : [ ]. How to update state in wrapper i have tried setTimeout but no use

Comment: Do you use https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter/ or else? This should be mentioned as the problem is specific to how you mock Axios.

Comment: Yes i'm using [link](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function that calls Axios is unreachable, a promise that it returns should be chained to avoid race conditions. Since `MockAdapter` doesn't specifically provide it, this should be done additionally:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Component/>)
jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');
wrapper.instance().getData()
expect(axios.get).toBeCalledTimes(1);
await axios.get.mock.results[0].value;
expect(wrapper.state('weekData')).toBe(['raspberry'])
```

For a function that is directly accessible, a promise that it returns can be chained. `getData` is an antipattern because it contains loose promise that cannot be chained. It should be:

```
getData = () => {
    return axios.get('/events/sept/week2/1097338')
    ...
```

Then it could be tested as:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Component/>)
await wrapper.instance().getData()
expect(wrapper.state('weekData')).toBe(['raspberry'])
```

Comment: Thank you Estus spyOn worked for me, 1st expect worked 
but still facing problem at await since im not using async

Comment: Then consider using it because await should be inside async function. This is reasonable here because the test is asynchronous.